# Convert a process based program into a thread based version?

Tags: c, multithreading, process, operating-system, pthreads

I currently have this program which spawns an arbitrary number of child processes and I'm interested in having it implement threads instead of processes. I'm having trouble understanding how to convert from what I have, here is the code which uses processes:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

void childprocess(int num);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  if (argc != 2)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s num-procs\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  int counter;
  pid_t pid = getpid();
  int x = atoi(argv[1]);

  printf("Parent Process, my PID is %d\n", pid);

  for(counter = 1; counter <= x; counter++){

    if(!fork()){
      printf("Child %d is born, my PID is %d\n", counter, getpid());
      childprocess(counter);
      printf("Child %d dies\n", counter);
      exit(0);
    }
  }
}

void childprocess(int num){

  srand(getpid());
  int max = rand() % 100;

  for(int i = 0; i < max; i++){
    printf("Child %d executes iteration: %d\n", num, i);
  }

}
```

Is it as simple as changing a few lines to make it use threads instead? I understand the theory behind using threads but not how to actually write it in C given what I have here

Comment: Search for `[c] pthread_create` to get some examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general case depends on whether the threads are wholly independent of each other.  If you go multi-threaded, you must ensure that any shared resource is accessed appropriate protection.

The code shown has a shared resource in the use of `srand()` and `rand()`. You will get different results in a multi-threaded process compared with those from multiple separate processes. Does this matter? If not, you may be able to let the threads run, but the C standard says the [`srand()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.2.2) and [`rand()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.2.1) functions don't have to be thread-safe.

If it matters — and it probably does — you need to use a different PRNG (pseudo-random number generator) which allows you to have independent sequences (for example, POSIX [`nrand48()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nrand48.html) — there may well be better alternatives, especially if you use modern C++).

The use of `getpid()` won't work well in a multi-threaded process either. Each thread will get the same value (because the threads are all part of the same process), so the threads won't get independent sequences of random numbers for another reason.

Comment: I see! I believe it would matter in this case! So the different threads can't be identified through the use of getpid(), I'm reading that instead I should be using some sort of a gettid() to return the thread's ID of the current process? Although it's not clear that that is something that can be implemented in C? Otherwise this program could be used to spawn an arbitrary number of threads?

Comment: Using `gettid()` to get a thread ID seems logical.   Whether it’s a good seed is debatable, but it is better than `getpid()`.  There probably is an upper bound on the number of threads, but it will probably be substantial.

Comment: Okay so I think I've somewhat implemented it with your advice, although it isn't functioning like the other program, should I update the question to include this code so someone can maybe take a look?

Comment: You could add the new code, leaving the old code also in place, but … since you’ve accepted my answer (thanks), a new question for the revised code is probably better.  You could include a link to this question to give context.

Comment: Okay thank you! I'll ask a new question with a link to this for reference, appreciate the help