# Spawning Arbitrary Number of Threads

Tags: c, multithreading, process, operating-system, pthreads

I'm trying to write a program which will spawn an arbitrary number of threads, similar to the code I have in [Convert a process based program into a thread based version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58826841/convert-a-process-based-program-into-a-thread-based-version/58828623?noredirect=1#comment103933798_58828623), which uses processes to do what I'm trying to accomplish, so far I have the following code, I'm getting a lot of warnings currently, but I'm really wondering if I'm approaching what I'm trying to do somewhat correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *runner(void *param); //the thread

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  pthread_t tid = gettid();
  pthread_attr_t attr;

  if (argc != 2){
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: a.out <integer value>\n");
    return -1;
  }

  if (atoi(argv[1]) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Argument %d must be non negative\n", atoi(argv[1]));
    return -1;
  }

  printf("My thread identifier is: %d\n", tid);

  // default attributes
  pthread_attr_init(&attr);

  // create the thread
  pthread_create(&tid, &attr, runner, argv[1]);

  // wait for the thread to exit
  pthread_join(tid, NULL);

}

void *runner(void *param){
  //int i, upper = atoi(param);
  int i;
  srand48(gettid());
  int max = nrand()%100;

  if (max > 0){
    for (i=1; i<=max; i++){
      printf("Child %d executes iteration\n", param, i);
    }
  }
  pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Appreciate  any guidance I can get with this!

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to include the warnings you want us to address.

Comment: @ikegami well there were quite a few... which leads me to believe that my syntax is off, but I can fix that on my own, I'm more concerned that the code isn't going to work for what I'm trying to have it do, logically, should what I've coded up spawn some number of threads correctly or am I missing some pieces?

Comment: There's only one thread creation call

Comment: @ikegami I had been under the impression that runner would give the thread creation call the number of threads to create.

Comment: `runner` is executed by the thread.

Comment: @ikegami so should I be executing the pthread_create in a random loop and not even bother with the runner function that I have?

Comment: regarding: ` pthread_t tid = gettid();`  this returns the TID of the `main()` function, which is `iffy` and of no interest to the program.

Comment: regarding; `printf("Child %d executes iteration\n", param, i);`  this is in a `thread`, not in a `child process`

Comment: @user3629249 so I don't need the thread id for creating the threads? And yes my bad, I was building off of another code which used processes to do what I'm trying to do here

Comment: The `thread id` is generated by the call to `pthread_create()` (first parameter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your objective, you want to create the number of threads as the command line parameter indicates.

(remembering that any specific OS can only support a fixed number of threads, which varies depending on the OS, so I will not validate the magnitude that number here.)

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. documents why each header file is included
4. checks for error indications returned from C library functions, like `pthread_create()`

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // printf(), perror(), NULL
#include <pthread.h> // pthread_create(), pthread_join(), pthread_t
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE, atof()

void *runner(void *param); //the thread

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <integer value>\n", argv[0]);
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // might want to use: `strtol()` rather than `atoi()` 
    // so can check for errors
    size_t maxThreads = (size_t)atoi(argv[1]);

    pthread_t tid[ maxThreads ];   
    for( size_t i=0; i<maxThreads; i++ )
    {
        tid[i] = 0;
    }

    // create the threads
    for( size_t i=0; i<maxThreads; i++ )
    {
        if( pthread_create( &tid[i], NULL, runner, (void *)i ) )
        { 
            perror( "pthread_create failed" );
        }
    }

    // wait for each thread to exit
    for( size_t i = 0; i<maxThreads; i++ )
    {
        // if thread was created, then wait for it to exit
        if( tid[i] != 0 )
        {
            pthread_join( tid[i], NULL );
        }
    }
}


void *runner(void *arg)
{
    size_t threadNum = (size_t)arg;
    printf( "in thread: %zu\n", threadNum );

    pthread_exit( NULL );
}
```

a run with no command line parameter results in: (where the executable is named: untitled

```
Usage: ./untitled <integer value>
```

a run with a command line parameter of 10 results in:

```
in thread: 0
in thread: 4
in thread: 2
in thread: 6
in thread: 1
in thread: 5
in thread: 7
in thread: 8
in thread: 9
in thread: 3
```

which makes it clear that threads are run in no particular order

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been trying to figure out how to do this for a very long time and failing to understand (I'm still very new to C programming), you make it very clear and easy to understand and I really appreciate you giving me something to work with!

Answer (score 2):

1: I see no function called **gettid()**

```
pthread_t tid = gettid();
srand48(gettid());
```

2: You cannot print pthread_t as an integer, it's a structure

```
printf("My thread identifier is: %d\n", tid);
```

3: it's rand(), I have not seen nrand() before.

```
int max = nrand()%100;
```

Fix these and edit the question if required.

Comment: I've edited the question and I appreciate you pointing out those errors! I know getpid() won't work for threads and I had thought that gettid() was a function in c. I was also under the impression that rand() was not good for threads

Comment: yes, rand is not safe, use drand48_r or erand48 instead

Comment: ok, so I've swapped out the line which used the gettid() with:     "pthread_t tid = syscall(SYS_gettid);" and the line which used rand() with:     "int max = drand48_r()%100;" does that seem like the correct way to go?

Comment: you don't need syscall, sorry I went to sleep last night before answering properly but @user3629249 is correct. next edit would have been about you creating just 1 thread in main. keep in mind you should create threads only from main.